# Puedo inyectar un dato en un input de una web fuera de mi Dominio

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

chicos tengo una consulta, yo poseo un sistema que gestiona la generacion y asignacion de codigos y seriales de tarjetas de telefono prepagadas, existe un sistema ONLINE que se encarga de efectuar la recarga desde el sistema de la operadora al telefono indicado, y tengo una duda y es la siguiente:
Existirá alguna manera de que desde mi sistema con mi dominio propio que logicamente es diferente al dominio donde esta alojado la web de recarga online yo pueda enviar 2 datos y que sean leidos en la web destino en los campos respectivos

```
codigo
serial
```

y que el usuario solo deba escribir el numero de telefono a donde se desea efectuar la recarga..?
Se que puede sonar imposible o por lo menos dentro de mis conocimientos no se si sea algo posible por eso consulto.
La web donde deseo efectuar la inyección desde mi dominio es: http://www.movilnet.com.ve/conweb/recarga_popup.jsp

Comment: Creo que tienes dos opciones: hackear la pagina insertando un script o buscar algun web service que lo haga. La primera es broma...

Comment: Estoy analizando el archivo javasacript de ejecucion y creo que podre declarar la variable antes de ejecutar el script de la pag. Estoy pensando..!! de no lograrlo no es problema porque mi idea es hacerle la vida mas facil a mis clientes pero si no se puede no queda de otra que lo sigan haciendo de manera manual..!!

Comment: Bueno asi como quieres no puedes